# How do I dynamically hide empty categories in toolbox of rehosted designer

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-rehosting

We are rehosting the designer and the System.Activities.Presentation.Toolbox.ToolboxControl in an application. We have very many activities, grouped into quite some categories in the toolbox (>300 activities in 50 categories...)

When I type some string into the toolbox search box, I would like to **disappear all categories that have no entry shown** due to the active search. At the moment, they all show up as headers without any content and more often than not, I have to scroll down to see the activity that I'm looking for - not really usable:

[image: example of empty categories]

Is there any way to achieve that, e.g. by setting CategoryItemStyle or CategoryTemplate on the ToolboxControl?

Comment: Did you find a way ? I know it's old but I've the same issue